# How to grab some digits from a number?

Tags: c

Let us say we have the following number.

Number = 2001000200030

How can I grab the first digit and store it to a variable? Then
 grab the next four digits and store them to another variable? 
Then the next four digits ...

So the output should be like this.

first = 2;

firstfour = 0010

secondfour = 0020

thirdfour = 0030

Thank you and I appreciate your time.

Comment: You could always convert it to a string and grab it by the bytes.

Comment: I wouldn't know unless I see an example.

Comment: I added an answer demonstrating how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Why use strings when you can stick with processing numbers? You can split by digits using modulo and division in powers of 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long long number = 2001000200030LL;

    /* Find power of 10 for top digit */
    long long currentDigit = 1LL;
    while((currentDigit * 10LL) < number) currentDigit *= 10LL;

    printf("First digit = %lld\n", number / currentDigit);
    number %= currentDigit;

    /* Read off groups of four digits */
    while(currentDigit >= 10000LL)
    {
        long long nextFour;
        currentDigit /= 10000LL;
        nextFour = number / currentDigit;
        number %= currentDigit;
        printf("Next four = %04lld\n", nextFour);
    }

    /* Output any remaining digits not covered by a group of four */
    if (currentDigit > 1LL)
    {
        printf("Remaining digits = ");
        for(currentDigit /= 10LL; currentDigit > 1LL; currentDigit /= 10LL)
        {
            printf("%lld", (number / currentDigit) % 10LL);
        }
        printf("%lld\n", number % 10LL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Numbers are stored on the computer in binary, because of this an integer has no capacity to distinguish individual digits.

Convert the number to a string and extract the parts you need. You can also convert each part back into a number if needed. (There are probably prettier ways of extracting parts of the string)

Also this code is for this contrived example, if the integer is unknown, this code cannot safely make the assumptions it does.

```
long long number = 2001000200030LL;

// convert number to string
char string[64];
sprintf(string, "%lld", number);

// access individual digits
string[0] (first digit)
string[1] (second digit)

// copy first four digits into an int
char firstFour[5]
memcpy(firstFour, string, 4)
firstFour[4] = "\0"; // null terminate
int firstFourInt = atoi(firstFour);

// copy second four digits into an int
char secondFour[5]
memcpy(secondFour, string + 4, 4)
secondFour[4] = "\0"; // null terminate
int secondFourInt = atoi(secondFour);
```

Comment: "cannot safely make the assumptions it does" - I'll give you an upvote if you say what the assumptions are :)

Comment: @TimothyJones haha, I  think the main one is that the length of the string is greater than 8 characters and less than 64. I think it should work for cases within that constraint.

Comment: Why not use `%8d` to sidestep the minimum length assumption? Also, your example won't compile on most systems, since `2001000200030` is greater than `2^32`. For extra credit, you could use something like `(int)log10(INT_MAX)+3` to determine the size of the `string` (+3 = +1 to make the maths work, +1 to handle minus signs if negative, and +1 for the null terminator)

Comment: @TimothyJones %8d is a good idea thanks. I didn't realize that the number is greater then integer capacity - I will modify it to a long.

Comment: @TimothyJones I think my answer provides enough understanding for the op to do what he needs. Other things to do, I will have to pass up on the extra credit this time :) Thanks for helping my answer out!

Comment: @TimothyJones ... or the return value of `snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", INT_MAX)`... One problem I see is that it ignores a possible sign. `INT_MIN` would actually be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void){
    int64_t number = 2001000200030LL;
    char data[24];
    char digit[5] ={0}, *p;
    int len, r;
    len=sprintf(data, "%lld", number);
    p = data;
    r = len % 4;
    if(r){
        strncpy(digit, p, r);
        printf("%s\n", digit);
        len -= r;
        p += r;
    }
    while(len!=0){
        strncpy(digit, p, 4);
        printf("%s\n", digit);
        len -= 4;
        p += 4;
    }
    return 0;
}
/* output
2
0010
0020
0030
*/
```

case of the number was a string, and output to string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char number[] = "2005001000200";
    char mode[2]={0};
    char red[5]={0};
    char green[5]={0};
    char blue[5]={0};

    strncpy(mode , &number[0], 1);
    strncpy(red  , &number[1], 4);
    strncpy(green, &number[5], 4);
    strncpy(blue , &number[9], 4);

    printf("Mode = %s\n" , mode);
    printf("Red  = %s\n" , red);
    printf("Green = %s\n", green);
    printf("Blue = %s\n" , blue);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail? strncpy "No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow)."

Comment: @JustinMeiners What is the specific case to fail if any?

Comment: digit is not guaranteed to be zeroed out with null termination. The number is more than 8 digits, strncpy will not null terminate it for you if the string is greater the length. Therefore digit is never null terminated, printf may fail. Sometimes the code will work, sometimes it won't. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JustinMeiners I think you're misunderstanding. Digit will end in a '\ 0' always.

Comment: It doesn't because of strncpy documentation above. So wouldn't the printf fail because it doesn't know where the string ends? (just tested if digit does not start \0 filled it fails)

Comment: @JustinMeiners I'm sorry, I am talking about null is not granted in the strncpy. Thank you has been fixed.