# How do you extract digits from number?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I asked similar question before but the answers weren't exactly what I was looking for, so this time I will provide more details.

I am programming a microcontroller using C language for the first time. I have an Android APP that allows the user to select a combination of colors (RGB colors) then sends the color code to the microcontroller. The microcontroller displays the light based on what was chosen.

What I am attempting to do is to be able to read the number by four digits at a time. So if the number that was sent is 2005001000200 I would like to do the following.

Extract the first digit and save it in a variable called mode ..Then.. Extract the next four digits and save them in a variable called red ..Then... Extract the next four digits and save them in a variable called green ..Then.. extract the last four digits and save them in a variable called blue. So the output should be like this ...

Mode = 2

Red = 0050

Green = 0100

Blue = 0200

If I can see an example illustrating what I am trying to do that would be awesome. Please keep in mind I am programming a microcontroller for the first time.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Is the value a string or a number?

Comment: The value is a number and it will always be 13 digits.

Comment: @Ammar Rephrased. It is a *binary* decimal number? Or is is a string of 13 **digit characters** sourced from... somewhere (like a text file, a console, etc.)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grab some digits from a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327662/how-to-grab-some-digits-from-a-number)

Comment: @WhozCraig Jesus Christ, what is a `binary decimal number`?

Comment: @DKrueger assume it is a string for now.

Comment: @Ammar If it's a string you use `sscanf(source_string,"%2d%4d%4d%4d",&mode,&red,&green,&blue)` straightaway.

Comment: @SheerFish its as close as I could come to asking if the number were a native integer type (which most will know, but judging by the OP's question, he may not). clarifying something that is a string of digits vs a real integer type to someone that doesn't necessarily think of them that way is *not* trivial. Heh, he figured it out though. (and thanks for the laugh =P)

Comment: @WhozCraig Well, you could ask how the number is represented... and then give examples of how it might be represented, in case the OP doesn't know what "represented" means... "For example, your *number* might be stored in an `unsigned long long`, `unsigned int`, or some other integer type, or it might be represented as a sequence of decimal (or *binary*, *octal*, *hexadecimal*) digit characters in a `char` array..." It would seem this was quite relevant to the question, since we all came up with different answers based on representation, and one seems to make more sense than the others, to me.

Comment: @SheerFish binary decimal, or bidecimal for short, might be a system of representing numbers using a set of twenty digits ;)

Answer (score 7):

Supposing I had `2005001000200ULL` in an `unsigned long long` somewhere:

```
unsigned long long value = 2005001000200ULL;
```

If I wanted to extract `blue`, I'd use a modulo operation:

```
unsigned long long value = 2005001000200ULL;
unsigned int blue = value % 10000;
```

To extract green, I'd use a division operation, followed by the same modulo operation:

```
unsigned long long value = 2005001000200ULL;
unsigned int blue = value % 10000; value /= 10000;
unsigned int green = value % 10000;
```

To extract red, repeat the process:

...

```
unsigned long long value = 2005001000200ULL;
unsigned int blue = value % 10000; value /= 10000;
unsigned int green = value % 10000; value /= 10000;
unsigned int red = value % 10000; value /= 10000;
unsigned int mode = value;
```

*Hey! I missed a step! :(*

Comment: `Is the %2d intentional? Your code appears to be parsing 14 digits`.What does it mean, tell me please.

Comment: @undefined behaviour, I can't build the code, its complaining about syntax error possibly from unsigned long long.

Comment: @Ammar Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Ammar ... and what's the precise error message, as it reads? From the looks of things, your compiler supports `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour .. I fixed the error, I was doing something wrong. Another question for you, I am using your first two lines to extract the blue digits. When I use 'printf("%d", blue2);' I get a number of 7295. How come it's not 0200? Thanks!

Comment: You should be using `%u` to print `unsigned int`s... `%d` corresponds to an `int` argument, and since the type is incorrect, the result is undefined behaviour. With that in mind, it's working fine for me: [here](http://ideone.com/tTxfOb). What is the type of `value`, in your code?

Answer (score 5):

If the format of the number sent is fixed, then you can use the following logic, if you are reading from the keyboard:

```
  scanf("%1d%4d%4d%4d",&mode,&red,&green,&blue);
```

That would do the job.

Else if it is in a file,use `fscanf()` to do it.I am sure using `fscanf()` is well-known to you.

And while we are at it, if that number is a string, then you can simply use `sscanf()` with a similar format specifier string.

Full example of use:

```
double input = 2005001000200;
char buffer[14];
sprintf(buffer, "%f", input);
int mode, red, green, blue;
sscanf(buffer, "%1d%4d%4d%4d",&mode,&red,&green,&blue);
```

Comment: +1 Considering all those leading zeros on the split-out provided by the OP, I can only assume it is indeed a char-input-source, and therefore a scanf() could/would work. I would check this to ensure it returns `4` parameters processed.

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed, hence I've added `sscanf()` as well to the list of options available to the OP.

Comment: +1 if the input is a number, using `sprintf` to convert the number to a char array and using the `sscanf` should work.

Comment: @Ryan Don't you think the answers to this following similar question by the same OP are unnecessarily complicated? Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327662/how-to-grab-some-digits-from-a-number

Comment: @WhozCraig Don't you feel the answers to a very similar or nearly same question by this OP are unnecessarily complicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327662/how-to-grab-some-digits-from-a-number

Comment: The number is always 13 digits. The app will send the number to the microcontroller and I will get it from the console. I am still not following you by the way. I hope to see a longer example, please don't mind my limited knowledge.

Comment: @SheerFish That was my thought while writing my answer... but even my answer looks simple compared to those D:

Comment: @Ammar It's really easy....Tell me which part you don't understand.Does the app send it as a number or as a string?

Comment: @Ammar If it's a number, you write it to a string using `sprintf()`,then read it back using `sscanf()` in the way I mentioned.If it's sent as string, then you can use `scanf()` straightaway.

Comment: @SheerFish Is the `%2d` intentional? Your code appears to be parsing 14 digits ;)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Can you explain your above comment.I didn't quite get what u mean to say.

Comment: @SheerFish, I am reading the number from the console, does that change anything? And I can't test the code now to verify it but I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: @SheerFish How many digits are in `"2005001000200"`? How many digits are expected in `mode`? How many digits are produced in `mode`? Your code leads the OP along the right path, but it is faulty in a pretty obvious way. I'm wondering if that fault was intentional...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour 13 digits eh?I mistook it for 14?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I corrected it.I really mistook it for 14.I hate 13 anyways,very inauspicious number.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour For a while I felt you assumed I am using  `double entendre` in my code.Why would I do that? :-)

Comment: @SheerFish Presumably the same reason you'd neglect the return value of `scanf`? I like to use `assert`, to make it painfully obvious that `scanf` does indeed return *something*, and that *something* should be done with it... *" ... but I dunno what `assert` does!"* ;)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I've to look up `assert` as I am not very knowledgeable about it.

Comment: @SheerFish It's basically internal documentation, and a handy debuggers aid. If you `assert(0 == 0);` you're telling the implementation (and anyone who reads your code) *"I'm fairly sure that `0 == 0` is true, but tell me when it isn't"*. So, when `scanf` fails, they get an assertion error instead of their program continuing and producing subtly fault-riddled behaviour ;)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Thanks for the finer details.

Comment: scanf is not supported in MPLAB C Compiler, so I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @Ammar Then use `fscanf()` by setting the filestream to `stdin`.

Comment: @Ammar BTW you do know how to use `freopen()`, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your value is stored is a string `s`, you can do the following:

```
int mode, r, g, b, n;

if((4 == sscanf(s, "%1d%4o%4o%4o%n", &mode, &r, &g, &b, &n)) && (13 == n)) {
    // Correctly scanned mode, red, green, and blue
    // Do what you need to do...
} else {
    // Failed to scan
    // Handle error...
}
```

Comment: Octal? I never thought of that... Interesting possibility... +1 for the `%n` and return value checks.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I think RGB values are normally one byte for each color -- and his four-character values always start with zero.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I wonder why hexadecimal wasn't used, considering it'd reduce the length of messages quite significantly (`"2284080"` vs. `"2005001000200"`).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I agree. It seems that Java's `Color.decode()` method handles both octal and hexadecimal (as well as decimal). Perhaps there is some historical reason for octal.

Comment: @DKrueger, I am getting this error 'could not find definition of symbol 'sscanf'

Comment: @DKrueger, scanf is not supported in MPLAB C Compiler.

Comment: MPLAB C is not C for similar reasons that Quake C is not C; the compiler is highly non-compliant. This question (and quite a few others) shouldn't be tagged C...